# Dynamic question display in salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have a requirement where i need to achieve the below structure

```
Question 1:
Answer 1 
Answer 2(selected this so below subquestion should open)
        Question 2
           Answer 1
           Answer 2
 Question 2:
     Answer 1 (selected this)
      Question 2
           Answer 1
           Answer 2
     Answer 2
```

The questions can increase in future at any level. So i want to set it up in a configurable way. Is there a way to do so without LWC and minimum customization?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please be aware this isn't a free coding service. If you want your question answered, you need to [edit] it to provide evidence of your research or what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. Read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for more detail on our expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post might help you.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree/example

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.